# What is the fastest ship in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship

What is the fastest ship in Star Wars?

Is it the [Republic Warship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Venator-class_Star_Destroyer) or something else entirely?

[image: The Millennium Falcon spaceship from Star Wars]

Comment: Is it friendship?

Comment: I asked is it the war ship!!!

Comment: How many parsecs does it do to the gallon? And can Barry Allen outrun it?

Comment: Sublight or hyperspace?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [Aing-Tii](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aing-Tii) monks have instant ships. (In the EU / Legends).

> "Their star drive is considerably different from ours. As you may have noticed from the battle. Instead of using the usual hyperspace travel, their ships are able to make an instantaneous jump to whatever point they wish." ―Jorj Car'das

I believe this makes them faster than even that old tired YT-1300 piece of junk called the Millennium Falcon.

Lando describes the Millennium Falcon as

> ..the fastest hunk of junk in the galaxy.

This could be read two ways, it IS the fastest ship in the galaxy, or it is the fastest one that is also a piece of junk. For all we know, brand new ships way out class the Millennium Falcon, but for an older ship, it is the fastest.

Comment: they essentially use dune tech to travel through space, and instead of spice they use the force >.< the idea theft was strong with these writers.

Comment: She may not look like much, but she's got it where it counts, kid.

Comment: @Himarm "Good writers borrow, great writers steal outright."

Comment: In *Return of Jedi*, Han insists that Lando should take the Falcon, saying: *She's the fastest ship in the fleet*

Comment: @LcSalazar Rebel Fleet = old and slow.

Comment: @JackBNimble A-Wings are fast

Comment: Can they make the Kessel Run in 12 parsecs?